# Error 450: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment on vba

Tags: vba, excel, macros

Im writing an excel sheet for work that when I press a button a loop runs through some rows and will edit some data if they're empty but I cant seem to get the macro to run as it keeps returning the 450 error.
heres a simplified version of the code that wont run.(starts at option explicit ends at end sub formatting is acting up when I paste in)

```
Option Explicit

Sub Copypaste()
'
' Copypaste Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+p
'
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim ls As Boolean

    i = 2
    j = 24
    ls = True

    Do While ls = True

        If IsEmpty(i, j) = True Then
            Cells(i, j).Value = 10
            ls = False
        Else
            ls = True
        End If

        i = i + 1
        j = j + 1

        If i > 10 Then
            ls = False
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Ive searched loads of threads and I cant seem to find anyone with the same issue as mine as any fixes ive made don't seem to be the problem.

New to macro as in discovered it today so could be a case of multiple errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change

```
If IsEmpty(i, j) = True Then
```

to

```
If IsEmpty(Cells(i, j).Value2) = True Then
```

Comment: Also, the `= True` is redundent

Comment: Thanks a Mil @Ralph, the redundant one I assume is at top of the while?

Comment: Actually, it was @litelite who suggested that you could skip the `= True`. While he is absolutely right I (personally) like to leave them in the code as it makes the code easier to read for me. But that's up to you and personal preference. If you wish to remove it you can do so in two places: (1) `Do While ls = True` can be truncated to `Do While ls` and (2) `If IsEmpty(Cells(i, j).Value2) = True Then` can be reduced to `If IsEmpty(Cells(i, j).Value2) Then`.

Comment: Perfect thanks less typing for me in future :) @Ralph